# Choice of elements for the MOSFET driver (circuit)

Tags: pwm, mosfet-driver, driver

Requirements:
600 V, 100 kHz (full-bridge)

MOSFET driver [L6388E](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6388e.pdf)

MOSFET - [Datasheet](https://www.way-on.com/files.html?id=24717)

Driver circuit (half-bridge):

[image]

PWM digital isolator circuit:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Cboot is used to power the top transistor. Is Rboot needed in this case? I have a 10 Ω resistor at the input.
2. I use pull-down resistors for the gate (R23, R24). What voltage should they be rated for? Can a 600 V potential appear on them? (In particular, the gate of the top transistor is pulled up to the middle point).
3. I've seen examples with a flyback diode and a series resistor to quickly discharge the gate.
   Is it mandatory to use it? I wouldn't want too many elements, but I'm also worried about reliability.
4. Are tantalum capacitors used to power the driver? I usually see ceramic ones.
5. I saw low-pass filters on PWM lines. I placed it at the output of the digital isolator.
   What is the cutoff frequency for these filters? If I choose a cutoff frequency near the switching frequency of the transistors I will see PWM distortion. By repeatedly reducing the capacitance of the capacitor, I will get rid of distortion, but the cutoff frequency will be about 7 MHz.

I collected those questions for which I did not find the answer. Any criticism of the schematic is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C15 (bootstrap cap) doesn't have to be rated for 630V as the voltage **across** it will be much lower (at Vcc level). If you have space and if your budget allows then keep it, otherwise you can replace it with one rated for 50~100V instead.

1. If you mean R22 (10R) with Rboot then you shouldn't place it in series with the IC's supply line as it may affect the operation. Instead, you can place an external diode from Vcc to Vboot, optionally with a series resistor. This resistor normally brings a slower recharge for the bootstrap cap so the Vcc rail is not overloaded with peak charge currents.
2. What matters is the voltage **across** the component, not the voltages at each end w.r.t. ground. Although the terminal voltages w.r.t. ground can be high, the voltage across the component will be much less (again, at Vcc level). So you can safely select 0603- or 0805-case resistors.
3. This is for a quicker turn off to prevent shoot through. Personally I'd place:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqK34D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gate will be turned on through R1+R2, and turned off through R2. Since these series resistances interact with the Ciss of the MOSFET, turn-on will be slower and turn-off will be faster (Q1 can be 3906 or equivalent and D1 can be 4148 or equivalent but must be a fast diode such as Schottky). R1 and R2 depend on the frequency and Ciss of the MOSFET but could be within 1~22 Ohms range. Make sure the filter they form with Ciss of the MOSFET doesn't chop or distort the pulses.). Alternatively, you can try the diode version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwUsYX.png)</sup>

Just like the one before, MOSFET will be turned on through R1+R2 but turned off through R1 only (neglecting the dynamic resistance of the diode).

4. Stay away from tantalum caps unless you know what you are doing. Ceramics can be used here.
5. Cut-off frequency can be calculated using the following formula:

$$
f_c =\frac{1}{2\pi \ R \ C}
$$

I'm not sure if the outputs require a filter but if they do then select the cut-off frequency beyond the switching frequency (e.g. 10 times or higher) or else you'll lose rising and falling edges and this is what MOSFETs are not happy with (for switching).

---

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You have answered all my questions!

Comment: Rohat Kılıç, Will this option work? I rearranged the top resistor and added a pull-down. https://imgur.com/a/t6fMDXo

Comment: @Delta can work. If your driver has push-pull (totem pole) outputs you normally don't need a pull-down but still you can place one, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Ok, Thank you!!